# extract substring using cshell

Tags: shell, csh

I need little help on extracting string using csh.
I have a variable containing a long string ending with _abc.
I need to extract the whole string except _abc using csh.
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the command `basename` available, in which case you want

```
echo `basename mystring_abc _abc`
>> mystring
```